# df['datetime']=df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'] > unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have in my df
date and time parameters and i want to combine the by  ane create datetime format
df['time'] is object
df['date'] is  datetime64[ns]

when irun this code

```
df['datetime']=df['date'] + ' ' + df['time']
```

I get

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeArray' and 'str'
```

what should I do?

should I  convert just df['time'] ?   if so ,I can I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need datetimes add times converted to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), because there are python times is necessary also convert to strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2015-01-01', periods=3),
                   'time': pd.to_datetime(['10:00:10','12:00:00', '05:02:03']).time})

df['datetime'] = df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str))

print (df)
        date      time            datetime
0 2015-01-01  10:00:10 2015-01-01 10:00:10
1 2015-01-02  12:00:00 2015-01-02 12:00:00
2 2015-01-03  05:02:03 2015-01-03 05:02:03
```

Alternative solution is convert first `date` and `time` to strings, join with space and last call [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))
```

Comment: the firt solution give ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>   but the secound was great.  thank you

Comment: @rafine - First was changed to `df['datetime'] = df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].astype(str))`, it should working too.